# How to deselect one segment when other is selected in UISegment iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, selected

This is what happening, 'Male' is primary so it remains selected and this happens when I select 'Female', please tell me why male is not deselecting itself?

[image]

this what I have done connected segment controller as `IBOutlet`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *genderSelection;
```

then in `viewDidLoad`: 
[

```
self.genderSelection addTarget:self action:@selector(MySegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)MySegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        // code for the first button
        NSLog(@"MALE");
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Female");
    }
```

This is my attribute inspector:

[image]

Comment: Add this line in function as first line: `[segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:segment.selectedSegmentIndex];`

Comment: are you test this in device..? This is not happening with me...I have just try it..

Comment: Maybe you have another place in code where selectedSegmentIndex is adjusted? For example, method linked to ValueChanged property as IBAction?

Answer (score 1):

You have to deselect the other segment in the selection "if".

so

```
- (void)MySegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        //You can use    segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;  instead
        [segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
        // code for the first button
        NSLog(@"MALE");
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        //You can use    segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;  instead
        [segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"Female");
    }
```

So you can switch between 0 & 1 indefinitly.

It could even be better if you used for a more dynamic selection, as suggested by Mrunal

```
[segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:segment.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

Comment: Nothing happening i am curious why on the start both highlighted or selected or in blue color :/

Comment: Wait i'm just realizing that your function isn't an `IBAction`

Comment: yes, but i have tried by connecting my segment controller as iboutlet as well as ibaction now i can't figure it out why on the start both segments are highlighted. i have checked every thing in attribute inspector too.

Comment: When you use breakpoints, does the if-else react properly? Or does the code completly ignore your function? What is happening when you go step by step, line by line

Comment: Oh you mean at the start. Okay. Maybe try selecting your index 0 (or 1) in the viewDidLoad

Comment: no it works fine I'm printing a message and it is printing correctly

Comment: done that too , what happen that in start it shows only index 0 selected but when i press index 1 both get highlighted

Comment: Now that's interesting. I'm thinking you missed something in the attribute inspector but you say otherwise... Do you have any other code related to that segmented control?

Comment: Yeah that could help, we never know ! Just the top "SegmentedControl" is required, for both segments parts

Comment: have u seen  ? if i am making any mistake in my attribute inspector

Comment: have you tried replacing 0 & 1 in the if-else by the segment index as suggested in the last part of my answer?

Comment: Yes i have put it before my if else to ensure selection but it didn't work!!

Comment: It is very unusual behavior i am trying to figure it out but not working for me

Comment: Now i'm starting to think we got this all wrong. It should be "select 1 when 0 is selected" in the if else. Not "select 0 when zero is selected". right? Otherwise you would be stuck on the same segment forever.
But you tell me that it works fine right? You can select both freely, its just a visual issue that "male" is always selected ?

Comment: But you still get "male" "female" "male" in the console when pressing it? Even though its if 0/0 else 1/1instead of 0/1 1/0?

Comment: Yes it is working fine in console , and NO it should be straight fwd like by default it should be 0 selected and when i select 1 it should be 1 and then again if i select 0 it should be 0

Comment: They don't change the selected indexes in any tutorial. Most of the time they just use a switchcase where they do "nothing" about the segment. (in your case, remove everything except  the NSLogs).
But again, i'm guessing you already tried without the "setSelectedSgmentIndex", right?

Comment: I checked here : http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/create-segmented-control-ios7.

This is VERY simple and straightforward and very similar to your code except for the switch case (which is the same as an IF).

Comment: Just deleted every previous piece of code and tried this one works fine, but i am still confuse what hack was wrong in my previous approach.

Comment: Hahhahahah i just did :D thanks for helping me buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Just deselect the first one in `else If`:

```
if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    // code for the first button

    NSLog(@"MALE");

}
else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Female");

    [segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];



}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)MySegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"MALE");
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex=1;  // this will make female selected.

    }
}
```